# Memory leaks from splitting and duplicating strings

Tags: c, memory-leaks, glibc

I am working on a fairly simple application written in C with GTK+ that is leaking memory badly. It has a few basic functions on timers that check the clock and poll an external networked device, parsing the string returned. The application runs on a small touch panel, and through TOP I can watch the available memory be eaten up as it runs.

I'm pretty new to C, so not surprised that I'm doing something wrong, I just can't seem to figure out what. I've been trying to use Valgrind to narrow it down, but honestly the output is a little over my head (10k+ line log file generated from running the application less than a minute). But in digging through that log I did find some functions repeatedly showing up with permanently lost blocks, all using some similar structure.

Example 1:
This is a short function that gets called when an option is selected. The last line with the g_strdup_printf is the one called out by Valgrind. select_next_show and select_show_five_displayed are both global variables.

```
static void show_box_five_clicked ()
{
g_timer_start(lock_timer);
gtk_image_set_from_file (GTK_IMAGE(select_show_1_cb_image), "./images/checkbox_clear.png");
gtk_image_set_from_file (GTK_IMAGE(select_show_2_cb_image), "./images/checkbox_clear.png");
gtk_image_set_from_file (GTK_IMAGE(select_show_3_cb_image), "./images/checkbox_clear.png");
gtk_image_set_from_file (GTK_IMAGE(select_show_4_cb_image), "./images/checkbox_clear.png");
gtk_image_set_from_file (GTK_IMAGE(select_show_5_cb_image), "./images/checkbox_checked.png");

select_next_show = g_strdup_printf("%i",select_show_five_displayed);

}
```

Example 2:
This is another function that gets called often and came up a lot in the Valgrind log. It takes the incoming response from the networked device, parses it into two strings, then returns one.

```
static gchar* parse_incoming_value(gchar* incoming_message)
{
gchar *ret;

GString *incoming = g_string_new(incoming_message);
gchar **messagePieces = g_strsplit((char *)incoming->str, "=", 2);
ret = g_strdup(messagePieces[1]);
g_strfreev(messagePieces);

g_string_free(incoming, TRUE);
return ret;
}
```

In all the cases like these which are causing problems I'm freeing everything I can without causing segmentation faults, but I must be missing something else or doing something wrong.

**UPDATE:**
To answer questions in comments, here is an example (trimmed down) of how I'm using the parse function and where the return is freed:

```
static void load_schedule ()
{
    ...other code...

    gchar *holder;
    gchar *holder2;

    holder = read_a_line(schedListenSocket);
    holder2 = parse_incoming_value(holder);
    schedule_info->regShowNumber = holder2;

    holder = read_a_line(schedListenSocket);
    holder2 = parse_incoming_value(holder);
    schedule_info->holidayShowNumber = holder2;

    ...other code....

    g_free(holder);
    g_free(holder2);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Right, so where do you free select_next_show?

Comment: Where do you free `ret` of example 2? Where do you free `select_next_show` of example 1?

Comment: Updated to show where `ret` is freed. select_next_show exists through the life of the program, so I didn't free it at the end of `main()`. I know that's bad form (and now I see could trigger some lost blocks in Valgrind), but that shouldn't cause it to continuously eat up more and more memory each time it's changed, should it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you free 'ret' once when calling g_free(holder2), but you've done multiple allocations for that one free - you call parse_incoming_value multiple times, each time causing an allocation, but you only free once right at the end.

As you copy the holder2 pointer into schedule_info elements each time, they actually have the "leaked" memory at the end.

If you do not free holder2 anywhere, but just free all the elements in schedule_info at the end of the code. I presume that shows no leak?

e.g.

```
holder2 = <result of dynamic alloc>;
schedule_info->a = holder2;
...
holder2 = <result of dynamic alloc>;
schedule_info->b = holder2;
...

// instead of g_free(holder2) at the end, do this...
g_free(schedule_info->a);
g_free(schedule_info->a);
```

Comment: Hmm...I see what you're saying, but how do I fix that? I can't free it multiple times, can I?

Comment: You need to free it before you place the contents of another allocation into holder2

Comment: I was not even aware you could free it then use it again after. This is likely my problem all along. Upvoting now for the knowledge, and will mark as the answer once I can confirm. Thanks!

Comment: I must still not understand. If I use g_free(holder2), allocate something else to it, then do g_free(holder2) again I get a double free error and crash.

Comment: Coulde you show code? Could you be freeing one item allocated to holder2 in two places? As you can see at https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Allocation.html#g-malloc "It's important to match g_malloc() (and wrappers such as g_new()) with g_free(), g_slice_alloc() and wrappers such as g_slice_new()) with g_slice_free(), plain malloc() with free(), and (if you're using C++) new with delete and new[] with delete[]. Otherwise bad things can happen, since these allocators may use different memory pools (and new/delete call constructors and destructors)."

Comment: Right after each schedule_info->...=holder2 line I added a g_free(holder2). It compiles okay, but blows up when I run it.

Comment: I'll change my answer above, as I suspect my reply won't fit in a comment field!

Comment: OK, that I can understand. But where do I put those schedule_info frees so that they will be run when my application window is closed? Will that happen if I just put them in Main after the gtk_main() call?

Comment: you don't need to worry about them, as they will be freed up when your application closes anyway - Valgrind is just warning you about them in case they would keep on growing (e.g. if your application ran for weeks/months and kept increasing its memory usage). In your example it sounds like it is not really a 'leak' you just have not freed all allocated memory at the end, but that will be tidied up when your application ends.

Comment: Ok, then my leak must be elsewhere, because the application slowly eats up more and more memory as it runs, even when it's sitting and doing nothing but checking the time.